# Noise stemming from resetting integrator

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog, noise, integrator

I employed an OP37 op amp to build an integrator as shown below.

There is noise caused by resetting the integrator. I made `V_IN` ground, and `V_OUT` is as following graphs. `CLOCK` frequency is 200 kHz.

- Why does this occur?
- How can I eliminate it?

[image]

[image]

`V_OUT`:

[image]

[image]

The used probe is a GTP-250A-2:

[image]

This is my new probe setup according to *Tony Stewart EE75* and *winny* comments:

[image]

These are the results for 1x and 10x probe, respectively:
(It is weird that the 10X result is worse.)

[image]

[image]

Something that I suspected was the redundant traces that I placed allow me to easily install capacitors with different values. I tested different capacitors with PXC connector (X2) as below pic. However, when I trimmed the capacitor legs and soldered it to C35 actual position, the noise only reduced 10 mV. So it is not likely the problem. Am I right?

One thing likely to be worth mentioning is that when I change `CLOCK` to 2 kHz, the same result will appear. (It may imply that rise time plays the key role, not the sampling frequency.)

[image]

Comment: You can't eliminate it completely as it is a tradeoff with the gain of your integrate & dump cct. What are your specs and tolerances? Why is there so much noise on the pulse? (probe gnd too long)  You choose 200 ns dump in a 5 us interval. This 4% ratio  is  too big.  What is your goal?

Comment: Yes probe GND is about 40 cm. But the thing that ruins my work is those spikes. My desired is to bring them below 50 mV. Now is about 600 mV. 200 ns time scale is brought only to provide information about the shape of spikes. What do you mean by `cct`?

Comment: You need proper probe setup to measure that small signals with that fast rise/fall times. Please show your probe setup. Is C31 and C33 MLCC? Where is your decoupling for IC8 and IC9?

Comment: The inductive probe ground loop needs to be shrunk down to a < few  cm for <50 ns risetime . Remove gnd and tip and coaxial gnd spring and probe pin, only on 10:1 probe

Comment: Also add 150 to 220 ohms in series with FET from cap  side to dampen risetime

Comment: @winny, Yes, they are MLCCs. I did not put any decoupling caps for IC8 and IC9. Are they effective to my problem? Ok, I try to use better probe setup and send an image.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75, Could you please describe why putting 150 to 220 Ω resistor makes it better? what do you mean by `from cap side`?

Comment: Assume all ICs need decoupling until proven otherwise.

Comment: Bravo on capture better results. Your probe bandwidth is now 10x and so unlike what I hoped , the inductive pickup is on your board layout and not the probe pickup.. V= Ldi/dt   with around 5nH/cm and can't see risetime of FET but appears to be <10ns and if RdsOn=1 ohm * 1nF load , you expect ns ballpark risetimes which makes it sensitive to track inductance. So adding a series R with FET Ciss is a low pass filter. Try to slow down the switch risetime to < 10% pulse width for now as ?~1% is too fast for this layout.  Even try your finger to ground around the switch signals to see effects.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 I put 220 Ω in series with Q2. Yet the result was approximately the same as before.

Comment: There are a few problems with this design and layout, that may not be fixed easily.  If I understand correctly, your new pulse is 500mV/div, not 50mV/div. The area under curve of the positive peak ought to match the lower peak, relative to the voltage before turning off the FET. so your pulse is 2.8 divisions or 1.4Vpk.  Since your OA has an input offset nulled by a pot the FET reduces the gain while but the input offset still exists. The 15MHz resonant signal  source is undefined and during FET =ON that reduces to about half 7MHz but damped.  So I can't see the entire circuit or cause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> these are the results for 1x and 10x probe, respectively:
> (it is weird that the 10X result is worse!)

This is normal, 1x probes have very low bandwidth, so the spike is there, but the probe lowpasses it, so you don't see anything. Also 1x probe loads the circuit a lot because it presents the full cable capacitance to whatever you're probing, so it will eat the spike and it will disappear when you probe for it.

If you want to watch something fast, always use 10x probe with tiny ground spring. The alligator ground clip has lots of inductance so on fast signals you'll see plenty of ringing, but that's just the improper probe grounding, when using the tiny ground clip, it's much cleaner. Also the alligator wire will act as an antenna and pick up noise from nearby DC-DC converters.

Now the solution to your problem is to use a switch with low charge injection like Spehro recommends, and you should do that, the chip is designed for this, you'll never get that clean with just a FET, so it's a worthy investment. But this won't solve your other problems...

First, don't put some 74LVC near analog stuff. They have fast edges and high current output, which means they make a lot of noise. If you still need to generate a pulse for the analog switch IC, try something quieter, slower, with lower output drive, like 74HC or AHC, and put a 33R SMD resistor in the output to avoid any ringing. And put a decoupling cap on them!

Second, I think there is a full ground plane on layer2, but it is not connected to the ground pour on layer1, which means there is no ground plane on your board.

[image]

I see the GND pin of the opamp decoupling caps are connected to the ground pour on layer1, so the layout software says "happy DRC! job done!" but the path the current flowing through these caps will have to follow to actually get where it needs to go is pretty complicated, in fact it will snake all over the whole board. So the spiky currents from 74LVC will put noise into absolutely everything.

Solution: get rid of the ground pour, have a continuous ground plane on layer2, and put ground vias on every thing that has a "GND" pin.

Comment: Very informative answer. Thank you. There is a full ground plane on layer 2 connected to layer 1 by `Via Stitching`. However, via stitching is not good at all around the IC6 (opamp).

Comment: Yeah, ground pour with via stitching needs tons of vias, otherwise it makes things worse because the top ground pour is only loosely connected to ground...

Comment: Could you please introduce a comprehensive book as a reference for designing PCBs? I need to extend my knowledge.

Answer (score 3):

It is capacitively coupled from the mosfet's parasitic capacitance.  The signal labeled "Integrator" slews too fast for the opamp to react to.  Since there is probably no need for it to be that fast I suggest using the slower version of the signal, taken from C38 and adjust R44 and C38 as appropriate.

An alternative solution may be shunting Q2's drain to ground and adding a resistor between it and V_OUT.

Because of your long ground lead inductance, the spike may be larger than is seen.

Don't leave CMOS inputs floating.  Connect IC8's S̅D̅ to something.

Answer (score 3):

Something like a 2N7002 will have a ton of charge injection. Commercial analog switches are designed so much of that cancels out. For example the [ADG1201](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADG1201.pdf) has 0.8pC typical charge injection, which should be almost 2 orders of magnitude better.

[image]

It is relatively high 'on' resistance compared to a 2N7002, you can look at other models if that is a problem. There are many available products.